# Lazybones Can't Use Cached Versions

Tags: aem, lazybones

I have downloaded the lazybones – lazybones-0.8.3 and used the command :
lazybones create aem-multimodule-project aemtraining
and
receive the response as below:
Creating project from template aem-multimodule-project (latest) in ‘aemtraining’
(Offline mode – run with -v or –stacktrace to find out why)

Cannot create a new project when the template isn’t locally cached or no version is specified

Could you please point me to a probable reason ?

Thanks in advance !
Regards,
Madiha

Comment: This error shows up sometimes when no version number is indicated in the create command. Try this -  `lazybones create <template name> <template version> <target directory>`. eg: `lazybones create aem-multimodule-project 1.0.0 my-project`

Comment: @SubhashSulanthar: Thanks, but changed command didn't work for me
I am relatively new to concept of creating fresh projects using either maven or lazybones, so possible to suggest something other than the version directive?    

Below is the execution of command as suggested by you
D:\MyDevelopmentPath\lazybones create aem-multimodule-project 1.0.0 my-project
Creating project from template aem-multimodule-project 1.0.0 in 'my-project'
(Offline mode - run with -v or --stacktrace to find out why)
Cannot create a new project when the template isn't locally cached or no version is specified

Comment: Can you try executing this script `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=11 -DarchetypeCatalog=https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/`. Refer to this article for detailed info --> `https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/maven_arch11.html`